# Error handling request with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I am getting "Error handling request" and I can't really trace this down to a particular problem?
I am using gunicorn+nginx and my gunicorn setup is

```
gunicorn run:app -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers=1 --timeout=300
```

here is the error message

```
2015-10-14 21:27:11,287 DEBG 'myserver' stderr output:
[2015-10-14 21:27:11 +0000] [26725] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
   response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

can anybody give me a hint how to debug this? I don't have much experience with server usage...
thanks
carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: This isn't an issue with gunicorn or nginx. Your view function in your Flask app is not returning a response. Check the return statement in your view function for whatever route you are accessing when you get this error.

Beginning at the Line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

You can see the stack trace produced by the python interpreter. The [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) shows the sequence of nested functions leading up to the point where your code failed. In my limited experience, the python interpreter stack trace has reliably directed me to the fault in my code.

In your case here, the final line:

```
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

provides some more detail about the error and should give you pretty good idea of what went wrong (Your view function didn't return a response).

The next line up from the bottom will show you the function that triggered the error, and its exact location in your code:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
```

In this case the error is raised by a function in the flask source, so unless you edited that, that is probably not where you need to make a fix. Based on the specific ValueError at the end of the trace, I'd go straight to my views function. In Flask that probably looks something like this (example from [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/)):

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

That last line seems like a good place to start in your case, since the error says nothing is being returned.